# Clicking second address on company page centers map on first address

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Was looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/kiandra-it. I scrolled to the company's second address and clicked on it (not an intuitive UI BTW). The map zoomed on the first address's location. It did not re-direct to the newly-clicked address.

Comment: Huh, for me it just goes to a specific zoom level wherever I am on the map, when I click the second address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed.

Thanks for your report!